# AD users getting locked out every 20 seconds

Tags: active-directory

I have been searching high and low for an answer, but I cannot seem to figure out why a few of our users keep getting locked out every 30 seconds. I unlock the account and then can watch the login attempts within seconds lock them out. I have tried tools like account lockout status and Netwrix, and I cannot find out what computer/service/task that is causing it. I did turn on netlogon logging, but it doesn't tell me which computer its coming from and it also doesn't say in the event viewer logs. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!
I have put an example event, and netlogon line below:

**Netlogon:**

01/04 11:51:07 [LOGON] [20280] DOMAIN: SamLogon: Transitive Network logon of (null)\John Jones from  (via WEB-SERVER) Returns 0xC000006A (there is nothing after from)

**Event:**

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xC000006D
    Sub Status:     0xC0000064

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x0
    Caller Process Name:    -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Comment: thought I should add this comment up here.

 
I have also checked our firewall, and there is no network attack happening. It all started when he logged in and his computer told him that it needed new credentials, so he locked his computer and unlocked it, and it has been locking out ever since. I have run multiple virus scans as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use LDAP integrated applications?

Advise those end users to clear browser cache (if not already) - if Windows users, clear credentials in:

Credential Manager->Windows Credentials->Delete all entries under "Generic Credentials"

Does your organisation authenticate users who connect to corporate WiFi using AD? If so check that the end users mobiles/tablet devices have been configured with the new password, best way to do this is to forget the connection and re connect using new credentials.

We've had very similar issues in the past and resolved doing the above.

Comment: No, we did that... we deleted all the credentials, and I cleared his browsing history and it still locks the account out. I dont understand why I am not getting any from workstation in netlogon, or on the event id.

Comment: Does the end user use VPN, RDP terminal sessions that might have a cached password?

Comment: No, nothing like that either.

Comment: Does your user's email account use AD password? If so have you signed out of Office applications / such as Word/Outook/ODFB, might also be worth getting the user to re configure/update the password on the users phone if the password is same as AD and the user uses emails on the users phone...

Comment: we use office 365 and email doesnt touch the domain at all. They are completely separate logins.

Comment: Something has to be hammering the DC, but I cant get any sort of log to show me an IP or workstation name... Netlogon.log or event viewer, not even third party tools can tell me where the logons are coming from.

Comment: I have also checked our firewall, and there is no network attack happening. It all started when he logged in and his computer told him that it needed new credentials, so he locked his computer and unlocked it, and it has been locking out ever since. I have run multiple virus scans as well.

Comment: Try to log the user into another machine and see if the same occurs, if not - maybe backup users data and create a new user profile - unless your roaming profiles are network driven?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently done this for myself.

The script can show you the timestamp, username, machine name where the lockout event is being originated.

Here is code:

```
# Set default parameters and variables
param (
    [string]$DomainName = $env:USERDOMAIN,
    [string]$UserName = "*",
    [datetime]$StartTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-3)
)

# check if current powershell version is 4 or higher

if ($Host.Version.Major -lt "4") {
    Write-Host "`n`nError: You need at least version 4 PowerShell for logging to work, `nCurrent version:"$Host.Version.Major -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor white
    Write-Host "`nBefore you start using this script, please upgrade your PowerShell from Microsoft website!" -BackgroundColor Yellow -ForegroundColor Black
    Read-Host "`n`nScript execution finished, press enter to exit!"
    Exit
}

# Grab the information about your AD forest
$Forest = [system.directoryservices.activedirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()

# Get list of all domain controllers in the forest
$DC = $Forest.domains | ForEach-Object {$_.DomainControllers} | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}


# Prompt user to enter a pacific username or accept default (which means look for all locked out events)
Write-Host "`n`nEnter a UserName to search user specific locked out events `n`nOR `n`nPress enter to search all locked out usernames!" -BackgroundColor Yellow -ForegroundColor Black
sleep 3

$TestName = Read-Host "`nPlease enter a UserName or Press enter"
if ($TestName -ne $null -and $TestName) {[string]$UserName = $TestName}



Write-Host "`nScript will search for locked out events on the following domain controllers..." -BackgroundColor Gray -ForegroundColor Black
$dc

# Search for locked out event of each DC and store them in variable
$dc | foreach {

    Write-Host "`nChecking for locked out events on $_, please wait..." -BackgroundColor Gray -ForegroundColor Black
    $OutPut = Invoke-Command ($_) {

    $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
    Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security';Id=4740;StartTime=$Using:StartTime} |
        Where-Object {$_.Properties[0].Value -like "$Using:UserName"} |
        Select-Object -Property TimeCreated, 
            @{Label='UserName';Expression={$_.Properties[0].Value}},
            @{Label='ClientName';Expression={$_.Properties[1].Value}}


    $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
    } | Select-Object -Property TimeCreated, 'UserName', 'ClientName' |Out-Host

    if ($OutPut -eq $null -and !$OutPut) {Write-Host "`nWarning: No lockout events were found!`nContinuing the search..." -BackgroundColor Yellow -ForegroundColor Black}
    else {$OutPut}
}
```